# How to get a file name from file url in Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

So I am trying to use apps scripts to make a function so that I can provide a file url and get the file name in app scripts. Here is the function that I have that keeps giving me a permission error.

```
function getSSName(url) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(name);
  return(ss.getActiveSheet().getName());
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a [custom functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)? or you plan to call this function from another function in your script? By the way `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(name);` `name` is not defined, it should be `url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
function getSSName(url) {
  return DriveApp.getFileById(url.split('/')[5]).getName();
}
```